# Best C++ library to interact with ICQ?

Tags: c++, icq

I have a Qt-based windows application written in C++ that needs to report it's status via ICQ and react on some ICQ messages. Maybe anyone know a good library to interact with ICQ? I need to connect ICQ with registered login and password, send messages to specified contacts and receive messages from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of two streamline options:

[libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) - The core library behind [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/)
[Telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/) - The core behind [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy)

Answer (score 1):

[qoscar.googlecode.com](http://qoscar.googlecode.com) - actual library, written on qt by me.